# Laravel - Multiple PostTypes models in relation to one CommentModel

Tags: laravel

A Laravel website with two sections: Post and Product Reviews. Both can be commented. So I have three models: Post, Advisor and Comment.

**My consideration**

**Post.php**

| id | title | content |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | post_title_1 | lorem 1 |
| 2 | post_title_2 | lorem 2 |
| 3 | post_title_3 | lorem 3 |

**Advisor.php**

| id | title | content | link | likes |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | advisor_title_1 | lorem 1 | www1 | 100 |
| 2 | advisor_title_2 | lorem 2 | www2 | 110 |
| 3 | advisor_title_3 | lorem 3 | www3 | 120 |

**Comment.php**

| id | related_id | type | comment_content |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | \App\Models\Post | lorem 1 |
| 2 | 1 | \App\Models\Post | lorem 2 |
| 3 | 1 | \App\Models\Advisor | lorem 3 |

```
// Two Comments for Post with id 1
// One Comment for Advisor with id 1
```

That's the theory. But I don't know how to write the relations. Therefore my question:
How should I write the relations in the Post and in the Advisor Model?

These are my models with their still "faulty" relations:

**Post.php**

```
public function comments() {
    return $this->hasMany(Comment::class);
}
```

**Advisor.php**

```
public function comments() {
    return $this->hasMany(Comment::class);
}
```

**Comment.php**

```
public function posts() {
    return $this->belongsTo(Post::class);
}

public function advisor() {
    return $this->belongsTo(Advisor::class);
}
```

How do I have to rewrite the relations in these three models. So that I can retrieve the following relations correctly?

1. $post->comments
2. $advisor->comments
3. $comment->post
4. $comment->advisor

Comment: I would check the Laravel docs on [polymorphic one-to-many](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many-polymorphic-relations) relationships

Answer (score -1):

This is a feature included in base laravel framework called polymorphic relationships, you should check out the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#polymorphic-relationships) here.

Comment: Do you know in which format to write the class in the field commentable_type? `App\Models\Post` or `App\Model\Post` or `App\Model\Post::class` or just Post?

Comment: @MaikLowrey laravel will automatically take care of that for you when you use the relationship by default it is `App\Models\Post` however you can override it check [this](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#custom-polymorphic-types) for info about that but generally you won't need to worry about it.